# What does it mean, if the LSM and LM are equal, but do not change for hours?

Tags: milestones, botbox

My Latest Milestone and Latest Solid Subtangle Milestone are the same, but they do never change and they are behind the numbers in [#botbox](http://iotatangle.slack.com/messages/C1SBL3S92).
What does that mean? My node is not fully synced, right?
What can I do against it, if my assumption is right?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you are out of sync

You could ask in the #nodesharing channel for a few new neighbours. Perhaps you chose some dead ones. You can detect dead neighbours if they are also behind

Additionally, try to restart your node. There are some weird syncing issues with the current iri version, this sometimes seems to fix it

Comment: thanks.
I have restarted it 4 times today, but it is everytime the same behaviour.
I have used a new DB snapshot to times, but it does not change anything.
So you think I have bad neighbors?

Comment: Have you already tried switching neighbours? I'm not an expert when it comes to full nodes, but these are the most common reasons for beeing out of sync

Comment: No I did not. I have my node since yesterday .... but this behaviour is everytime the same ... ok, I will try to add/change neighbors, thanks again

Comment: @WolfgangEgger if my answer helped you, please accept it.